# Defining a Realm Database Structure (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, database, realm

I am in the process of creating an application that will display a list of stocks that a user saves in a tableView. It will also allow the user to add or remove items from their favorites. I need help defining the database structure and setting up for the adding and constant updating of the user's favorite stocks.

I currently have a StockData struct that works with my tableView and a button for adding to the user's list:

```
struct StockData {
    let currentPrice: Double    
    // meta data
    let name: String
    let ticker: String
    let interval: String
    let lastRefreshed: String
    let change: Double 
}

// In an actual ViewController
@IBAction func addButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    print("Add clicked")
    // Handle adding the item to the user's list
}
```

Now as far as my current realm model is concerned, I have:

```
class User: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name = ""
    @objc dynamic var id = ""

    var stockFavs = List<StockItem>()
}

class StockItem: Object {
    @objc dynamic var currentPrice: Double = 0.0
    // meta data
    @objc dynamic var name = ""
    @objc dynamic var ticker = ""
    @objc dynamic var interval = ""
    @objc dynamic var lastRefreshed = ""
    @objc dynamic var change: Double = 0.0
}

// Setting up the user and creating test values
        let newUser = User()
        newUser.name = "John Smith"
        newUser.id = "coolId123"

        var stockArr = List<StockItem>()
        for i in 0..<12 {
            let item = StockItem()
            item.name = "Microsoft Corporation"
            item.change = -3.55
            item.currentPrice = 123.45
            item.interval = "1day"
            item.lastRefreshed = "Now"
            item.ticker = "MSFT"
            stockArr.append(item)
        }

        newUser.stockFavs = stockArr

        try! realm.write {
            realm.add(newUser)
        }
```

So far, I have been able to create a user object for the current user of the device and add test values, but I am unsure how to implement constant realm updating (the method would have `self.tableView.reloadData()`, but apart from that, I'm clueless) in conjunction with the ability to add `StockItem`'s to the user's array.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You use a function for every time you want to add to the database.

```
let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(add), for: .touchUpInside)

func add() {
  let currentData = [MyFakeData1, MyFakeData2, etc.]
  try! realm.write {
    realm.add(currentData)
  }
  // You need to get the updates in the database
  // You could have an array in your model that you update and then append all
  // the new items to it and only do database lookups when you restart the 
  // device
  update()
}

func update() {
  let realm = try! Realm()
  var newArray = realm.objects(StockItem.self)
  myViewController.modelArray = newArray
  table.reloadData()
}
```